# How to use GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application I have `recyclerView` and for this I should use `GridLayoutManager` and set 2 items per column.

I want set this 2 items fit of screen, each items sticky to screen. Such as below image:

[image]

I write below codes, but after run application show me such as **this :**

[image]

And I want set **120dp** for `layout_width` and `layout_height`!

**My XML code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rowMasterQuestion_root"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_120mdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_120mdp"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_border">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowMasterQuestion_title"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_120mdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15mdp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9font_mdp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowMasterQuestion_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15mdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10mdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10mdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20mdp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5mdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5mdp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_8font_mdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**My Activity codes :**

```
requestMain_childList.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@RequestMainPage, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            hasFixedSize()
            adapter = masterChildAdapter
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky because you are wanting a different layout gravity for each item, depending on the column. I think that will have to be set in the `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder` function.

First, wrap the ConstraintLayout of your item view in a FrameLayout. Make the width of the outer FrameLayout `match_parent` so it will fill its column in the RecyclerView. You can also give the FrameLayout the amount of start/end padding you want to hold the items away from the sides of the screen.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrappedView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_120mdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120mdp"
        ...>

    ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in `onBindViewHolder`, you can set the gravity of the inner view to the left or right depending on which column it is in (even or odd data position).

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // ...
        val innerView = holder.wrappedView // or however you have it stored in view holder
        (innerView.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or 
                (if (position % 2 == 0) Gravity.START else Gravity.END)
    }
```

Note, if you want the items to be centered in their columns instead, this is much easier. You can just set the gravity of the inner view to `center` in the XML and you don't have to do anything in the Adapter.